# $Z$-transform of floor($\frac{n}{5}$)

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, z-transform

I found problem about floor array that I can't solve.
Find Z transform of f(n) = floor(n/5).
I tried writing this array and for n from 1 to infinity, I got n/5 = 1/5 + 2/5 + 3/5 + 4/5 + 5/5 + 6/5...
Now, taking floor for these numbers floor(n/5) = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1.. +2 +2... +3...
This means that for n>0 my array can be rewritten as floor(n/5) = 5*n. I was wondering if this is right and if Z{floor(n/5)} = Z{5*n}?

Comment: Please take the time to type up your question using MathJax; it's not complicated and you don't need much (enclose in dollar signs and write \lfloor \rfloor for floor, mostly). A guide is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x[n]=\lfloor n/N\rfloor$ we have $N$ identical (but shifted) summations

$$X(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^{-Nk} + \cdots + \sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^{-Nk-N+1}$$

$$= \frac{z^{-N}z^{-0}}{(1-z^{-N})^2} + \cdots + \frac{z^{-N}z^{-(N-1)}}{(1-z^{-N})^2} = \frac{z^{-N}}{(1-z^{-N})(1-z^{-1})}$$

which does not line up with your guess.